# Layout size increase and decrease dynamically in android

Tags: android, view, textview

I want to display text dynamically,like [image] What I wanted is displaying some text, then on click of button "view>" text gets displayed in a box.

What I tried is doing it using 2 textviews as

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                android:text="some text"
                                    />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="view >>"
                android:textSize="9sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                android:text=" yes"
                                  android:textSize="11.0sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

code:

```
public void onClick(View v)
 {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.button1:
            tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
}
```

What happened was that the 2nd textview is displaying text on the first. So is it possible to display text like this? Otherwise what should be done to overcome the messed up textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is normal. Indeed you have used a RelativeLayout and you have put the both text at the same place (with the margin attributes). So you can use a LinearLayout instead of a Relative Layout, or you can change the position of the second textView by modifying margin value, or by using `android:layout_below`.

Comment: thanx,i tried using  Linear layout it was working fine ,except that it was leaving empty space after button (as i was using this code twice i.e one more such textview group)which was not looking good,secondly i have already used  layout_margin concept as shown above

Comment: To remove the empty space replace <code>android:visibility="invisible"</code> by <code>android:visibility="gone"</code> normally this make that the element is not take in consideration for the view building (until it becomes visible, of course).